# How to deal with similar fields across SQL Server database tables in a dimension

Tags: sql-server, architecture, data-warehouse

I am working on a data warehouse solution, and I am trying to build a dimensional model from tables held in a SQL Server database. Some of the tables include but aren't limited to Customer, Customer Payments, Customer Address, etc.

All these tables in the DB have some fields that are repeated multiple times across each table i.e. Record update date, record creatuin date, active flag, closed flag and a few others. These tables all relate to the Customer in some way, but the tables can be updated independently.

I am in the process of building out a dimension(s) on the back of these tables, but I am struggling to see how best to deal with these repeated fields in an elegant way, as they are all used.

I'll appreciate any guidance from people who have experience with scenarios like this, as I ammjust starting out

If more details are needed, I am happy to provide

Thanks

Comment: you keep one of the fields and rename the others so that you do not have conflicts. to make it easy to understand where the fields come from and since they have the same name, you could try <origTableName_fieldName> or maybe an abbreviation of the original table name if that works best

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought about that, but was unsure if that's the right approach or if there was another way to do it, as I'll end up having a lot of similarly named fields with a subtle difference

Comment: What is the problem in having fields with same names in different tables? I would not change their names (the sample fields you mentioned) because each one is specific to its table. If you are creating dimension tables, you name them based on the dimension, but I am just curious if these are all separate fact tables they shouldn't overlap right?

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your reply. The tables I mentioned above all come from normalised tables that are part of a Database. These tables all hold content related to a customer. What I am trying to do is to create a customer dimension from these tables, and I am struggling to fully understand how to deal with the these dates correctly. Obviously, I can't have a dimension table for all of these individual tables, as they all hold information related to the customer, so my goal is to consolidate them into the customer dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Before you even consider how to include them, ask if those metadata fields even need to be in your dimensional model?  If no one will use the Customer Payment Update Date (vs Created Date or Payment Date), don't bring it into your model.  If the customer model includes the current address, you won't need the CustomerAddress.Active flag included as well.  You don't need every OLTP field in your model.

Make notes about how you talk about the fields in conversation.  How do you identify the current customer address?  Check the CurrentAddress flag (CustomerAddress.IsActive).  When was the Customer's payment?  Check the Customer Payment Date (CustomerPayment.PaymentDate or possibly CustomerPayment.CreatedDate).  Try to describe them in common language terms.  This will provide the best success in making your model discoverable by your users and intuitive to use.

Naming the columns in the model and source as similar as possible will also help with maintenance and troubleshooting.

Also, make sure you delineate the entities properly.  A customer payment would likely be in a separate dimension from the customer.  The current address may be in customer, but if there is any value to historical address details, it may make sense to put it into its own dimension, with the Active flag as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wes. As I am new to all this, you have raised a lot of valid points I didn't consider. The point about the address is really valid, as we would like to capture historical addresses. Thanks a lot for this and I will start to engage with my business users and ask more questions

Comment: Keep in mind that models are for analytics.  For the address dimension, you can certainly do analytics on city/state/zip, but what analytics can you run on Street Address?  How many orders do we have from 123 Oak St?  Or Boulevards vs Lanes?   I am sure there are some use cases, but very, very few models need the full address.